# Why is my jasmine spy not called?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am currently writing a unit test for Geolocation API.

My Angular component looks as follow:

```
export class HeaderComponent {
  public lat: number = 56.713;
  public lng: number = 21.1644;
  public message: string;
  public messageType: string;

  public locationSuccess(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data) {
      if (data.coords) {
        this.lat = data.coords.latitude ? data.coords.latitude : this.lat;
        this.lng = data.coords.longitude ? data.coords.longitude : this.lng;
        this.messageType = 'success';
        this.message = 'You successfully granted us retrieving your location to ' +
                       'enhance your experience.';
      }
    }
  }

  public locationError() {
    console.log('error');
    this.message = 'Unfortunately we could not acquire your location which is recommended ' +
                   'for best user experience with our service.';
    this.messageType = 'danger';
  }

  public enableNavigatorLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        this.locationSuccess.bind(this),
        this.locationError.bind(this)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And my unit test looks like this:

```
// synchronous beforeEach
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('enableNavigatorLocation should call locationSuccess if successful', () => {
  const locationSuccess = jasmine.createSpy('locationSuccess');
  const locationError = jasmine.createSpy('locationError');

  spyOn(navigator.geolocation,'getCurrentPosition').and.callFake(function(locationSuccess, locationError) {
    const position = { coords: { latitude: 32, longitude: -96 } };
    arguments[0](position);
  });

  comp.enableNavigatorLocation();

  expect(locationSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My spy is not called and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Could there be a problem with the function call via `bind()` in `enableNavigatorLocation` method?

I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106008/how-to-fake-return-calls-from-the-geolocator-in-jasmine) from 2012 as a guideline

Comment: Is navigator declared like so `declare var navigator: any;` ?

Comment: @trichetriche where has this line of code to go? directly after the import statements?

Comment: No, I mean, you don't declare your navigator variable by `let navigator = 'something';` so I'm, asking, is that a global variable declared with `declare var` in your component ?

Comment: yes it is globally declared as `declare var navigator: Navigator;` in lib.es6.d.ts

Comment: then take a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099179/test-component-with-declare-var) which explains how to handle those cases.

Comment: @trichetriche I do not think that this is the problem because it has access to navigator and its functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because spying went wrong.

`locationSuccess` and `locationError` spies are local variables. They are never used. The fact that params in `callFake` have same names doesn't affect anything.

The proper way to do this is to stub  `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`:

```
spyOn(navigator.geolocation, 'getCurrentPosition');

comp.enableNavigatorLocation();

expect(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  comp.locationSuccess,
  comp.locationError
);
```

Comment: this throws `Expected spy getCurrentPosition to have been called with [ Function, Function ] but actual calls were [ Function, Function ]`.

Comment: and what is a proper way to test success and error then?

Comment: I see. The proper place to bind callback methods is class constructor, `this.locationSuccess = this.locationSuccess.bind(this)`. Not the place where they are called. You should test them in a separate test by calling them and putting `expect`s on component properties that they are supposed to set.